# class Derived(Base.User) vs class Derived(User)?

Tags: python, inheritance, syntax

I have two files main.py and user.py. What is the reason for using `class Derived(Base.User)` and not simply `class Derived(User)`? I also don't understand the use of `#` in `#Base.User.__init__(self)`.

main.py

```
import Base
class Derived(Base.User):
    def __init__(self):
       #Base.User.__init__(self)
       return
```

Base.py

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def displayName(self):
        print("Name : ",self.name)
```

Comment: `#` is just a comment in Python. It doesn't get interpreted

Comment: Are the two files, main.py and user.py in the same directory? How are they organized, it looks like user.py should be in a Base module

Comment: If your import for `Base.User` would be `import Base` and your import for just `User` would be `from Base import User`, there would be no difference between `class Derived(Base.User)` and `class Derived(User)`. Without the info @c6754 asked for, though, we don't really have any way of knowing.

Comment: @VineethSai damn totally forgot about that.

Comment: @c6754 edited it, user.py is actually Base.py. Yes, they're in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are three common options for importing from a module

***Import the `Base` module***

```
import Base
```

and then access the elements (e.g. the `User` class) of the module as `Base.User`.

***Import individual names***

You can just import individual names from the module by using an import statement like

```
from Base import User
```

Once you have done that you will have direct access to the `User` class as though you defined it in the current file. For example you can call

```
class Derived(User):
```

***Import every name in the Base module***

Instead of just select names, like the `User` class, you could import everything within the `Base` module into your current file. Do that with

```
from Base import *
```

Then any class or function defined in `Base` is accessible, i.e. you can just use `User` not `Base.User`.

Here is some more information about using and importing modules in Python [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)